# Not able to sign in or publish a report in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When I am trying to sign in or publish a report in Power BI, I am getting an error like the image link I have provided below. At that time I am not able to enter anything over there and couldn't even close the application it got stuck there, so every time I need to end that by using task manager. Could anyone please help me with this issue!

[The image of the issue I'm facing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yLjfIX1TehJP8BAxoeigrFcQ4_4Zsv8m/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like your single sign on is getting in the way. Go to the PBI service log in, you can then load a report from there, using the get data option. That will allow you to upload your desktop file via the browser

Comment: @Jon ok i will try that